# Import useless headers

Tags: ios, objective-c, import

I have a big project which is refactored a lot.

Some `classes` import unnecessary `headers`.

> #import "someClass1.h"
>
> #import "someClass2.h"
>
> #import "someClass3.h"

f.e:

`classA` in interface has:

> #import "classB.h"
>
> #import "classC.h"

`classB` in interface has:

> #import "classC.h"

So that import `classC` in `classA` interface could be removed...

I would like to have my `project` clean and tidy.

I'm just wondering:

- Is there a way to find useless imports quickly?
- What is best way for such situations and organizing one interface import of other interfaces?
- Does it affect on application performance if you have plenty of useless/duplicated imports?

Any help appreciated

Comment: Try to use JetBrain's [AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/)'s Code/Inspect Code option.

Comment: According to the Apple [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapOSX/books/WriteObjective-CCode/WriteObjective-CCode/WriteObjective-CCode.html) of Objective-C, the unnecessary imports are ignored.

"_When you want to include header files in your source code, specify a pound import (#import) directive as one of the first lines in a header or source file; a #import directive is like C’s #include directive, except that it makes sure that the same file is never included more than once.)_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) No there is no a way you need to check if that import is used in your file (use find function for this);

2) The best way is import **UNTIL IS POSSIBLE** **header in implementation file** (`.m`). If you need to declare that class in your header file (`.h`) you can use:

```
@class nameClass
```

before begin with `@interface`...etc.
If you already know that instead you need to import that class header file in your header, you can do it. Be careful to avoid `#import` cycle. In fact suppose to have this situation:

**MGCustomViewController.h**:

```
#import "MGViewController.h"

@interface MGCustomViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

**MGViewController.h**:

```
#import "MGCustomViewController.h"

@interface MGViewController : MGCustomViewController

@end
```

This cause an error at compile time, because you *inherit* from `MGCustomViewController` but importing `MGCustomViewController.h` you are importing again this last header before that the compiler read the `@interface MGCustomViewController` directive and so will show an error that says something like **SUPERCLASS NOT FOUND**.

3) No, but effects on the **compile time**.

Comment: import cycle that is if both interfaces import each other? Why it's so dangerous?